# Certain websites will resolve to a "server not found" error ONLY for me, but other people are able to access them - why?

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm developing some websites for a client and I pushed all the content to the web server.  The websites in question are:

```
quikcap-d.capworx.net  
www-t.capworx.net
```

Every browser on my computer reports an error when trying to navigate to them - Firefox says "server not found", IE immediately puts the web address as a search term and navigates to Bing to search the internet (like it does when it can't find the server), and Chrome says "Oops, Chrome could not find quikcap-d.capworx.net".

I ask other people to check these sites and they work for them.

I've tried flushing my DNS but that didn't help.  I've cleared all cache and internet history from my browsers, still no go.  My internet connection is good - I can get to anywhere on the web.  Could this be a DNS problem, or not since I'm the only one affected?  Any ideas???

**UPDATE**

Here's a screen shot of NsLookup:

[image]

Here's `ipconfig /all`:

[image]

Comment: Try using public dns for name resolution. Google's, for example - 8.8.8.8

Comment: @strangewalker The IP address is shared for my subdomains, I'm on shared hosting.

Comment: so? I'm being able to see your login page and get name resolution to 23.91.112.4

Comment: LOL I'd REALLY appreciate any feedback that's causing this question to be downvoted,

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, the *next step* to figuring this out will be investigating DNS. Do you know how to run nslookup? Post the results here - both for you (who it's not working for) and from these "other people" who say it's working for them.

You can use those results to figure it out.

Comment: I added a screenshot of NsLookup from my own machine.  Will work on getting the others, but can you deduce anything from the screenshot?

Comment: WTF. That's not running an nslookup command from your own machine, that's running an nslookup via a web interface, which is *someone else's* nslookup results. What light could that possibly shed on the problem you're having with hitting the site from your own machine? You know how DNS works, right?

Comment: JESUS dude, give me a break man.  I'm OBVIOUSLY not that familiar with DNS.  I will look up how to do this from my own machine.

Comment: So, the site resolves for *me*, giving the same results as the screenshot you posted. What are the results from nslookup against quikcap-d.capworx.net from *your* machine, the one that *having the problem* ?

Comment: Open a command prompt and type `nslookup quikcap-d.capworx.net`. Tell us what you get.

Comment: done, screenshot updated

Comment: OK - so your DNS server, which Windows says is unknown, doesn't have an answer. What does your system use for a DNS server?

Comment: What does my local machine use for a DNS server?  Not exactly sure what you mean.  Sorry, I'm more of a developer than a server admin.

Comment: ipconfig /all - and you need to learn about DNS if you're going to be administering *anything*.

Comment: ipconfig /all posted

Comment: OK - so your machine is using your router as a DNS server; which is probably just proxying the requests to your ISP's DNS servers. Maybe it's caching them too, which could be part of your problem. I've answered the question - it's not showing up for you because you can't resolve it. It's showing up for others because they can resolve it. You're going to have to learn some basic DNS troubleshooting, especially if you're providing these services to clients for money.

Comment: I appreciate it, but I build websites/web apps.  Very rarely do I need to ever deal with anything like this.  I don't administer anything - that's why I always deal with a "managed server" with a reputable company that can deal with all the server admin sorts of things.  Anyways, thanks again for your help. +1, btw.